# How to use multiple global interceptors in NestJS

Tags: http, web, nestjs, interceptor

I had already know we could create global interceptors from this code below:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { APP_INTERCEPTOR } from '@nestjs/core';

@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
      useClass: LoggingInterceptor,
    },
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Source: [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors)

However, what if I want to have let say, `UserInterceptor`.
`UserInterceptor` will get user from database and transform the request.
`UserInterceptor` need to inject let say `UserService`.
And I want to use `UserInterceptor` globally.

```
@Injectable()
export class UserInterceptor {
  constructor(private readonly service: UserService) {}
}
```

From [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#binding-interceptors), we can't do `app.useGlobalInterceptors(new UserInterceptor())` because `UserInterceptor` need 1 argument in the constructor (UserService).

And since we had use `APP_INTERCEPTOR` for `LoggingInterceptor`, I didn't found another way to assign another value to `APP_INTERCEPTOR` to use the interceptor globally.
For example I think the problem will solved if we could do:

```
providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
    useClass: [LoggingInterceptor, UserInterceptor]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```js
providers: [
  {
    provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
    useClass: LoggingInterceptor
  },
  {
    provide: APP_INTERCEPTOR,
    useClass: UserInterceptor
  }
]
```

Just like this

Comment: Wow! It's really staightforward and simple. Could someone explain to me how this could work? or where to find how this could work?

I never think this way because I think the APP_INTERCEPTOR in nutshell only assignable to an instance.

Comment: Very quick explanation of how: Nest is watching for these `APP_*` providers, and ends up attaching a uuid to the token so that you can have multiple values for the single provider token.

Comment: This is documented somewhere ? I have not found [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#binding-interceptors) it and I was about to ask the same question on SO.

Comment: @FlavienVolken nope, I just figure it out by reading the source code.